# QGIS 3.10 crashes constantly when performing join with virtual layer

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, virtual-layer

I want to create a pie-chart map showing the amount of groundwater extracted from different aquifers within different administrative areas like in the picture below:

[image]

I have a shapefile with groundwater extraction points ( ~ 7500) containing exploitation amounts and the associated aquifer the groundwater is extracted from as well as a polygon shapefile with the administrative area (~710).

First, I populate the exploitation amounts per aquifer within the different administrative polygons using a virtual layer and a spatial join between the points and polygons. I need this layer only to create the columns containing the aggregated exploitation amounts per aquifer and administrative area. I want to use this attribute-only table (with no geometry) as a join table for the administrative areas that will give me finally the information for the pie chart diagram.

In order to speed up the creating of the virtual layer I came up with the following SQL query that works slow but fine:

```
SELECT 
  
  GWsums.GID_2
, MAX (CASE WHEN GWsums.aquifer = 'n13' THEN GWsums.GWsum END) AS n13 /*:real*/ 
, […]
, MAX (CASE WHEN GWsums.aquifer = 'qp3' THEN GWsums.GWsum END) AS qp3 /*:real*/

FROM 
        (SELECT a.GID_2, sum(p.exploitation) as GWsum /*:real*/, p.aqui as aquifer 
         FROM GWpts AS p JOIN ADM2_District AS a ON st_contains (a.geometry, p.geometry)
         WHERE a._search_frame_= p.geometry
         GROUP BY a.GID_2, p.aqui) AS GWsums

GROUP BY GWsums.GID_2;
```

In the subquery, I calculate the amounts of exploitation per aquifer over the polygons. The outer SQL statement performs a pivot with the result set from the subquery, retrieving the six different aquifer exploitation amounts as columns with the administrative unit identifier GID_2 for the pie chart diagram.

Trying to join the resulting virtual layer to the polygons within the property dialogue causes QGIS constantly to crash.

Using a virtual layer to perform the data aggregation for the final pie chart visualization seems to me straight forward and I need to keep the whole workflow as simple as possible. It should therefore produce as few layers as possible.

Any suggestions or ideas on what could cause QGIS to crash when performing the join with the virtual layer?